# How to configure elasticsearch testcontainers to use the latest ES

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, testcontainers

```
testCompile "org.testcontainers:elasticsearch:1.14.3"
```

How to configure elasticsearch testcontainers to use the latest ES (say 7.9.2), the above is using a 6.4.1 image instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the place where you start the test container, just specify the desired image name:

```
ElasticsearchContainer elasticsearchContainer = 
  new ElasticsearchContainer("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2");
elasticsearchContainer.start();
```